# Fluentd filter exception - kubernetes centralized logging

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd

I’m trying to add centralized logging on my kubernetes cluster. I have installed EFK stack using  as an example. All is working fine, but the logs from my application are in string format and I want to write logs in elastic search as json.

I found a solution using a filter in fluentd, something like this:

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  hash_value_field parsed
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

My problem now is that not all pods are logging as json format and this generates parse exceptions in fluentd.

How can I filter these logs that are json and keep other logs unchanged?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide additional information: 1. What is the `parse exceptions`? 2. How do non-json logs look like? 3. Results of command `docker info | grep 'Logging Driver'` from each node